# How to get the size of the memory allocated by posix_memalign on MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos, memory

When googling regarding this topic, I did folowing finding:
`std::aligned_alloc` (C++17) / `aligned_alloc` (C11) niether work on Windows and MacOS (at least MS VC++ and Clang respectively). So I need to use `_aligned_malloc` (Win) and `posix_memalign` (Mac) and free them with `_align_free` (Win) and `free` (Mac) calls. All of this I was able to find out from documentations.

But as I want also to get the size of the allocated memory behind the pointer I found that on Win `_aligned_msize` for memory allocated by `_aligned_malloc` must be used. Unfortunately I had no luck finding any information for getting the size of memory allocated by `posix_memalign`.

Only finding I did, related to MacOS function for getting the memory size, was using `malloc_size` when memory was allocated by *"normal"* `malloc`.

**But is usage of `malloc_size` ok also for memory allocated by `posix_memalign`?**

Unfortunately I do not have any OsX machine available to test this myself.

Comment: I do not think this is explicitly documented. The Apple-provided man page for `posix_memalign` says the pointer it returns can be used in subsequent calls to `realloc` and `free`. So it seems it ties into the regular `malloc` data, and it would be a bizarre implementation if `malloc_size` did not work on it. That makes it something I might use in a pet project but not in a deployed product. You might consider reporting the lack of documentation to Apple in their Feedback Assistant. Of course, if I could not test on a Mac, I would not deploy for it anyway.

Comment: Thank you for feedback. As I was going through source code posix_memalign I got the same impression, but it is as you said - for production code it is clear no go for me. I will have to test it somehow on the Mac first.